# iPhone 3, iPhone 4 and iPad specific resources

Tags: iphone, ipad, retina-display

iPhone<4 (<3, 3g, 3gs), iPhone 4 and iPad all have different screen resolution. I want to make my iOS application graphics to be perfect quality to all of these devices. In other words, I want to have unique graphics for iPhone <4, iPhone 4 and iPad.

I know I can in runtime check which device we are using but could I do this anyway at build time? In other words, can I make an application to AppStore that is specific to iPhone's below version 4, and other version of the application for iPhone 4, and another version for iPad? So that all of these applications are named the same, and are actually the same application. But they contain only the device specific graphics (this way the application's size is smallest as possible).

Or do I need to submit one application to AppStore including all of the different graphics? So that even the iphone3 version contains iPad graphics?

Comment: They'd have to be separate apps with different names, or you have to put all the graphics into one app. But note that you don't necessarily need to do that. You can just have the high-res retina graphics and scale them for iPhone 3 and iPad as needed.

Comment: But ain't that slow performance-wise to use very high resolution images and scale them down?

Answer (score 1):

You can just include multiple versions of your graphics. You should have the iPhone < 4 versions named `myImage.png` and the retina display versions named `myImage@2x.png`. The correct image will be used automatically for the appropriate device.

With the xib files, you can put a suffix `-iPhone` and `-iPad` to distinguish them.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only submit one application per name to the app store. If you submit a different application build it will replace the previous one. You need to [create a Universal application](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW24), and name your resources (images, nibs) with device idioms (basically appending -iPad, -iPhone) to them.